# `window.onload` faild to run after asigning `window.__proto__ = prelude` , but why?

Tags: javascript

I by `prelude` mean this object: http://gkz.github.com/prelude-ls/
Seems not good idea to bind `prelude` to `window.__proto__`, though.
I'm curious and confused about why this happend, and my code in Chrome:

```
window.__proto__ = prelude;
window.onload = function(){
  console.log('loaded');
}
```

Comment: you're overwriting the entire `proto` object. you probably meant to add the `prelude` object to the `proto` object instead.

Comment: I was looking for a conciser way to do that. Given that's a wrong solution, I will assign each key/value on `window` object instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__proto__` is a non-standard reference to the prototype of the window object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

In your first line you are overwriting the entire prototype of `window`. This means that everything else previously written to the prototype object gets list, including native functions that could be responsible for invoking `window.onload`.

You should typically never overwrite the prototype object, but instead extend it or simply add new properties directly to objects like `window`.